# Laravel retrieved data object in object

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my **ArticleController** I have:

```
public function index()
    {
        $article= Article::with('ratingAvg')->get();        
        return view('article.index',['article' => $article]);
    }
```

And in my **Article** model:

```
public function ratingAvg()
    {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Rating', 'article_id')
        ->selectRaw('article_id AVG(rating) as rating')
        ->groupBy('article_id');
    }
```

In **article.index** :

```
@foreach ($article as $a)
  <p>{{$a}}</p>
@endforeach
```

As a result I receive the following data from the database:

```
{"id":10,"name":"Article1","rating_avg":{"article_id":10,"rating":"4.0"}}
```

When running `dd($article);` in the **ArticleController** I receive:

```
Collection {#194 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Article{#188 ▼
      #table: "articles"
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:12 [▶]
      #original: array:12 [▶]
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "ratingAvg" => Rating {#195 ▼
          #table: "ratings"
          #connection: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #perPage: 15
          +incrementing: true
          +timestamps: true
          #attributes: array:2 [▼
            "article_id" => 10
            "rating" => "4.0"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is, how can I display the **rating** value from the rating_avg object?

Comment: what is the result of `dd( $a );` in the for loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
$article = Article::with('ratingAvg')->get();
```

you are eager-loading this relation:

```
public function ratingAvg()
```

So you should access the relation in the view this way:

```
@foreach ($article as $a)
    <p>{{ $a->ratingAvg->rating }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Damn it, I always tried like it was in the response, `{{ $a->rating_avg->rating}}` and didn't work. Works now, thanks a lot

Comment: it's `ratingAvg` because the eager-loaded relation has this name: `Article::with('ratingAvg')->get();`